# Set default portlet Preferences

Tags: liferay, portlet

i'm trying to set portlet preferences, without touch the portlet.xml.

Here is my portlet :

```
-myportletclass
-myportletjsp
-myconclass
-myconfjsp
```

When I click on preferences, I can see the confjsp, wich display a form for my preferences. And, when I submit it, set the preferences to the values in the form.

But I don't have any default values, without modify the portlet.xml.

What shoul I add and where?

I saw some do it in the render of the config class, but it doesn't work their way.

Regards. 
Thank you.

edit : the way i set my preferences :

first, i have a simple form i my conf jsp, basic, no need to add it;
Then, i have the ConfController :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("EDIT")
public class ConfigurationController {


    @ModelAttribute("validatePref")
    public ValidatePrefForm getValidatePrefForm() {
        ValidatePrefForm form = new ValidatePrefForm();
        return form;
    }

    @ActionMapping(params = "action=validatePref")
    public void processAction(@ModelAttribute("validatePref") ValidatePrefForm form,
            PortletPreferences portletPreferences, ActionResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        String mylink = form.getMylink();




        if (null != mylink && !mylink .equals("")) {

            portletPreferences.setValue("mylink ", mylink );

        }

        portletPreferences.store();

    }

    @RenderMapping
    public String render() throws Exception {
        return "myportletjsp.jsp";

    }

}
```

And then, in my portlet i have this to get the value:

```
mylink= preferences.getValue("mylink", mylink);

        if(null==mylink){
            mylink= mydefaultUrl;

        }
```

And then i can use mylink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: portlet.xml is an excellent place to have default portlet preferences.

If you absolutely don't want this for some reason, of course you can check if the preference is `null`, then assume your defaults. Simply do this whereever you retrieve the portlet preferences - in the action-, render-, event- or resource-phase.

Comment: But in the second way, seems when i add a new instance of the portlet, it keep the preferences i set for a portlet already in the page. How can i fix it : have the default when i had the portlet in a page. Thank you. Edit : if possible, i prefere a way without using portlet.xml, but i don't exclude it.

Comment: @Jean: How are you setting your preferences? Because I think the portlet preferences are set for each portlet instance added to the page and not for the portlet or user as a whole. Liferay also sets default for the preferences, you can check `init.jsp` (if you have the source) for liferay's built-in portlets.

Comment: If you're not sure of you, don't worry it works to with the portlet.xml, just in case.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf this helped resolve an issue I was having